# encountered a co-ordinates out of bound exception - copying a picture into grid format

Tags: java, exception, pixel

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{     
   Picture sourcePicture = new Picture("C:\\caterpillar.jpg");

   int grid_size = 2;   

   Picture GridPic = makeGrid(sourcePicture, grid_size);

   GridPic.show();
}

public static Picture makeGrid(Picture sourcePicture, int grid_size){
  Picture gridpic = null;
  int picheight = sourcePicture.getHeight();
  int picwidth = sourcePicture.getWidth();
  Picture calculatedPic = new Picture(picwidth*grid_size, picheight*grid_size);
  int xStart =0, yStart = 0;


  for(int i = 0; i < grid_size; i ++){
      for(int j = 0; j < grid_size; j ++){
          calculatedPic = CopyPictureTo(sourcePicture, calculatedPic, xStart, yStart);
          xStart = xStart + picwidth;
      }
      xStart = 0;
      yStart = grid_size * picheight;
  }

  return calculatedPic;
}

public static Picture CopyPictureTo(Picture sourcePicture, Picture calculatedPicture, int xStart, int yStart){
  Pixel sourcePixel = null;
  Pixel targetPixel = null;

  for(int sourceX =0, targetX = xStart; sourceX < sourcePicture.getWidth(); sourceX++, targetX++){
      for(int sourceY =0, targetY = yStart; sourceY < sourcePicture.getHeight(); sourceX++, targetY++){
          sourcePixel = sourcePicture.getPixel(sourceX, sourceY);
          targetPixel = calculatedPicture.getPixel(targetX, targetY);
          targetPixel.setColor(sourcePixel.getColor());
      }
  }
  return calculatedPicture;
}
```

The objective of this program is to make a square grid layout from the source picture by copying and pasting all pixels. (It extracts the color of the pixels and sets the colors)
I face an array out of bounds exception in the following line. Can't figure it out. Help please.

```
 targetPixel.setColor(sourcePixel.getColor());
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   Coordinate out of bounds!
>     at
>   sun.awt.image.IntegerInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown
>   Source)
>   at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown
>   Source)
>   at
>   bookie.SimplePicture.getBasicPixel(SimplePicture.java:303)
>    at
>   bookie.Pixel.getAlpha(Pixel.java:73)
>      at
>   bookie.Pixel.setColor(Pixel.java:213)
>     at
>   com.picture.Picture.CopyPictureTo(Picture.java:189)
>   at
>   com.picture.Picture.makeGrid(Picture.java:170)
>    at
>   com.picture.Picture.main(Picture.java:103)

Comment: Always paste the full stack trace of the exception when you get one and want help about it.

Comment: I've added it; if this is what you meant by stack trace. Sorry I'm a beginnner.